# Stripe Create Recipient using php code

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I want to transfer money from Stripe account to third party Bank Account. So from stripe docs i have to create a recipient to transfer money. Here is my code from https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/sending-transfers

```
require_once('Stripe/lib/Stripe.php');    
Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");

// Get the bank account details submitted by the form
$token_id = $_POST['stripeToken'];

// Create a Recipient
$recipient = Stripe_Recipient::create(array(
  "name" => "Nitin patel",
  "type" => "individual",
  "bank_account" => $token_id,
  "email" => "xxxxxxxx@gmail.com")
);

var_dump($recipient);die;
```

I am not getting any error but it is not working. Can anyone please help me to create recipient or transfer to a third party bank account from stripe.

Comment: recipients are deprecated and no longer supported, they have been replaced with the Managed Accounts API. Also please don't share your secret API key

Comment: Please can you share the docs of Managed Accounts API in place of Recipients.

Answer (score 1):

The recipients API is deprecated, and has been replaced by [Stripe Connect](https://stripe.com/connect).

You can find the documentation for Stripe Connect [here](https://stripe.com/docs/connect). The documentation includes plenty of examples and code samples in all languages supported by Stripe, including PHP.

Also, it looks like you're using an older version of the [Stripe PHP library](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php#stripe-php-bindings). You should upgrade to the latest version. Note that the syntax changed in version 2.0: all `Stripe_Class` should be replaced by `\Stripe\Class`.